# How to throw error message if profile image size exceeds? D6

Tags: 6, media, users

I have enabled picture support and given the maximum size of an image as 30KB.

But if i upload profile image larger than the maximum size the the image is being uploaded and no error messages is thrown.

My case is:

> If the size of an image is larger than the maximum size given in 
>   **user/settings -> Picture Support** it should **throw an error message**.

What should i need to do?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: one way is to handle at the browser using jquery.